# Filling up a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to fill up a list of strings called lines with values from a dictionary called  A in python.A is filled with integers.The pseudocode  should be something like this.

```
 for i in xrange(0,256):
    for j in xrange(0,768):
        lines[j+4+(512*3)*i]= str(A[i,j])
```

As you can see I cannot insert the elements serially in lines.Is this possible? If it is then how should I do this? The list lines would be pretty large of size 786435. It depends on both i an j.I would be greatly obliged if anyone can help me.BTW I am using python 2.7  .

Comment: That's a big number (a list with 10**6+ elements!), and not all indices will have a value. Are you sure a list is the right data structure here? If this is a sparse sequence (not all indices have values), consider using a dictionary instead.

Comment: It's not a sparse sequence, every index position does have a value. They are not filled in serially though. Based on my algorithm each set of index position is filled in a different way.I just gave the code for one set of values.So what do you suggest I use as a data structure

Comment: Creating a list with over a million strings is going to put some serious strain on your memory requirements.

Comment: Using a dictionary works though. I actually need to write whole thing into a file later and the index position of the lines  should correspond to the line number of the file. I cannot actually think of any work round in the given scenario.

Comment: Are the strings of a *fixed length*?

Comment: yes 3 chars since the A[I,J] stores an integer value from 0 to 255

Comment: But will you store `0` in that line in the file, or `000`?

Comment: If they are of a fixed length, you can write a sparse file. An index then translates to a write position; including the `\n` newline you can write each number at file position index * 4.

Comment: Only 0 and that's the way they are stored in A[i,j]

Comment: Then your strings are not a fixed length; they are variable between 1 and 3 characters in length. Can you do this the other way around, determine what string you'll produce for a given index? `4` for example maps to `str(A[0, 0])`, `1540` maps to `str(A[0, 1])`, etc.

Comment: You *can* however, map indices directly to `i` and `j` coordinates. You don't have to store everything in a list up front; just start counting at `0` and produce the right string for that index to write to the file.

Comment: Yes I could , originally I was given a file ,I had to fill in 4 dictionaries with 4 regions in the files. The 4 regions were not sequential. Then I had to carry on manipulation on the 4 dictionaries. After all this was done I had to put back the changed dictionaries back into the files in the original order that i extracted them. I am still not very well versed in python. I could not get a specfic line from a file directly without iterating through it first.

Comment: i was filling up lines so that the index of line would correspond to the line number of the file. Is there a way to directly write into a file with a given line number?The other contents of lines are as follows:                                     for i in xrange(0,256):
        for j in xrange(768,1536):
            lines[j+4+(512*3)*i]=str(B[i,(j-768)])

Comment: Yes, those formulas can be converted to indices too. Just use the same `//` division and `%` modulus calculation and check those resulting `i` and `j` numbers against the ranges you are using there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Sir . I finally figured out what you were trying to tell me. I have optimized my code according to your suggestions. Thanx again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are *contiguous* sequences of elements. You could create the list up front, storing a reference to `None` at each index:

```
lines = [None] * (255 + 4 + (512 * 3) * 767)
```

but then you'd be creating an object with 1,178,371 (1 million plus) elements in it. That'll take a fair amount of memory *just for the list object*:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof([None] * 1178371)
9427040
```

That's 9MB for the list object alone, where each reference points to the same `None` object (it is a singleton, there is only ever one in memory). Add strings, and memory requirements rapidly climb; that many *empty* strings requires 40+ MB:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof('') * 1178371
43599727
```

In Python 2, every additional character will add a byte, so add average string length times 1MB to the requirements for *just this list*. If your strings are only 3 characters, that's still doable; that'll be about 50MB in total, but if you are talking about 5000 character strings you easily end up in the gigabytes. 5000 characters isn't all that much.

Your indices are not contiguous, however. You only are producing 255 times 767 is 195585 indices; you appear to have a *sparse* data structure. You'd be better off using a dictionary in that case:

```
lines = {}
for i in xrange(0,256):
    for j in xrange(0,768):
        lines[j + 4 + (512 * 3) * i]= str(A[i, j])
```

This works as written, because now each index is a key in a dictionary instead.

If you do have to produce a continuous sequence, consider different techniques. If all your indices, from 0 through to the very last, can be computed like the above, you could produce each value *by calculating*; given an index, calculate what string would be placed at that index. That way you don't have to produce all values up front.

The above loop indices follow a specific pattern, so you can simply derive the `i` and `j` from a given index:

```
def str_for_index(index):
    i = index // (512 * 3)
    j = (index % (512 * 3)) - 4
    if 0 <= i < 256 and 0 <= j < 768:
        return str(A[i, j])
```

Comment: Thanx I will use a dictionary instead . I just change the code and it works too.However i am not using a sparse data structure. Indeed every index position has a value.They are not filled in serially though. Based on my algorithm each set of index position is filled in a different way.I just gave the code for one set of values.

Comment: @user220789: over a million elements in a list is probably not going to work *anyway*. You may have to seriously reconsider your algorithm.

Comment: Using the dictionary works , i mean the code does what is supposed to do. But as you said it does utilize a lot of memory. I actually have to read an image file and store the bytes. Later I have to do a lot of manupulations on them.